# Bloomberg OVML| FX option pricing | Python

Tags: option-pricing, programming, bloomberg, volatility-smile, volatility-surface

Wanted to check if any API for python is available to replicate Bloomberg's OVML.

The objective is to perform FX options pricing for multiple positions, and we are getting stuck in calculating volatility for the BSM.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Calculating Vol is essentially unrelated to OVML, which is simply Garman Kohlhagen (with all the "nasty" details like daycount, etc being dealt with automatically). Seems what you really need is market data? Bloomberg has a direct API for this (to get IVOL from OVDV). You would also need to use CTK (curves toolkit) which is not directly available for free for BBG users.

Comment: Thanks..Can shed some light on the API?

Comment: Best to ask the help desk (F1 F1). They will not help with Python (programmatic API) but show how OVDV in Excel will work. https://www.bloomberg.com/professional/support/api-library/ is what they will refer you to for installing the Python API (WAPI page on terminal). How many positions is multiple really? MARS would do that all conveniently within the Bloomberg eco system and you can upload loads of deals in one go via csv.

Comment: We are talking about 25K positions and I need to price them. MARS has extended functionality which I dont really need nor do I want to save/record the positions for later reporting. Getting vol table in excel shouldn't be an issue.Wanted to check if there is any way I can directly get vol through API post giving expiry and strike and valuation date. What best option do I have.Thank you for your quick responses.

Comment: 25K positions will not be possible without an additional license. I recommend you reach out to your account manager, or if you do not want to pay for an additional license, get your market data elsewhere and write your own tool (or use quantlib for example). However, if you really have a need to price 25k positions, paying for a license (whatever provider you trust) to get reliable tools should be worth it.